# How to calculate how many primes there are of $N$ bits

Tags: prime-numbers, distribution-of-primes

Is there a way to calculate how many primes are *exactly* $N$ bits in length, without generating them? I know that you can calculate how many primes are below $N$, but not how/if you can calculate primes that are exactly $N$ bits.

Comment: If you can compute how many primes $n_j$ are below $2^j$ and how many primes $n_k$ are below $2^k$, with $j < k$, then $n_k - n_j$ should be your answer.

Comment: Umm I'm no maths whiz - could you write that up in steps?

Comment: With no user input other than the bitsize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest number with $N$ bits is $2^{N+1}$  The largest number with $N$ bits is $2^{N+2}-1$.  If you find the number of primes below $2^{N+2}$ and subtract the number of primes below $2^{N+1}$ you have the number with exactly $N$ bits.

Comment: This solution works, but would be slow when working with 2048 bit integers

Comment: @Legorooj If speed is your concern then nobody knows the exact formula for the $k$-th prime hence unfortunately there is no shortcut and you will have to generate all the primes as Ross mentioned in his answer

Comment: @Legorooj:  You can get very close with the prime number formula.You said you knew it could be done, so I assumed that

Comment: I know. This answers my question, I was just hoping for speed. Thanks!